# bigquery operation time out in europe west 3

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

All of our datasets have location europe-west3 in BigQuery and it's been going fine until last weekend. Suddenly all read queries fail to retrieve any data and hit operation timeout. When we changed some tables to an EU location dataset, we can query the table normally again. I checked all BigQuery limits and we’re far from reaching any limit. This is all in the same project and we don't use slot reservations. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

It may have  various root causes, possibly outage to the region, un optimize query that hitting some limits in BigQuery and etc. I would recommend narrowing this down with looking through logs ([Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging?hl=en)), or contacting Google for support to investigate your resources internally.

Additional Links:

- [GCP service health overview](https://status.cloud.google.com/)
- [BQ Query Optimisation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview)
- [Contact Google](https://cloud.google.com/contact)